# c# enum GetValue() method

Tags: c#, enums

I am working on some code written in c#. There is an enum, say defined as:

```
namespace abc
{
    public enum XYZ
    {
         a=0,
         b=1,
    }
}
```

Now, inside the code there is a variable, say x of type XYZ enum and a line :

```
var y=x.GetValue();
```

Now, when x is 0 ,i.e. "a", the code works properly and y is assigned "a". But when it is 1, the code crashes. I tried searching for the method "GetValue" but couldn't find much literature. Also in enum definition is the comma after "b=1" okay? Please help me out.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the code crashes"? Is there an exception? Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: *'XYZ' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'XYZ'*

Comment: The error was "A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll"

Comment: Could you give me some links about this GetValue() method?

Comment: *"Also in enum definition is the comma after "b=1" okay"* Yes, its legal code.

Comment: Have you considered type casting? `XZY xyz = (XYZ)0;` or `int i = (int)xyz;`

Comment: @whoisj I don't exactly get what you mean, like the variable x is already assigned something and the code wants to assign its string value (here "a" or "b") to y.

Answer (score 0):

`XYZ` is an enum, it does not have a value, you need to get the value of the entry you want from within it.

```
var y = XYZ.a
```

An enum binds a value to an enumaration, if you want it the other way around, you are best off using a `dictionary`, or list of `KeyValuePair`s instead.

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: as per comment, if you really want to use an enum, you can access it 'backwards' like so, getting the key from the enumeration:

```
enum WeekDays { Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat };
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
                     ((WeekDays)2).ToString()
                     ); //Prints "Mon"
}
```

Comment: C# enums are just `int` under the hood.

Comment: The variable x has some value say 0. Now, I think the code intends to give the string value of x that is "a" to y by the GetValue() method. I don't know much about this method (or c# for that matter, I have just started working with c#).

Comment: @whoisj not entirely true, you can define them to have a different underlying type, like `enum foo : byte { x, y, z }`

Comment: @Kaelan Fouwels, the code is written by other people and is quite a huge project, and I don't want to change the structure too much by replacing enum with dictionary.